# Getting string from SQLite database and checking if is equal to a variable doesn't work

Tags: java, sqlite, minecraft, bukkit

So what I'm trying to do is store a username and GUID in a SQLite database. When a new player joins the Bukkit server, the server gets the player's username and generates a GUID. The server gets this GUID and gives it to the player so that he can verify it. The username and GUID are now stored in the SQLite database. If a player joins the server with an unverified GUID, he gets kicked. So I need a way to track whether the GUID is verified or not. That's why the SQLite database contains an integer named 'verified'. If the integer is 0, the GUID is unverified. If it's 1, it's verified. Here's how the table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE AUTH (USERNAME CHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, GUID CHAR(36) NOT NULL, VERIFIED INT NOT NULL)
```

It doesn't matter whether the SQL statement is correct or not, as long as it gives you a basic understanding of how my table looks like.

So the problem I'm experiencing is with the code that kicks the player if his GUID is unverified/null.

```
// Check whether player has a GUID
if (playerDatabase.hasGUID(player)) {
    // Check whether GUID is verified
    if (playerDatabase.isGUIDVerified(player)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I did a couple of tests and found that the hasGUID boolean always returns false. Here's the code for hasGUID

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM AUTH;");

while (resultSet.next()) {
    if (resultSet.getString("USERNAME").equalsIgnoreCase(player.getName())) {
        if (resultSet.getString("GUID") != null) {
            statement.close();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is surrounded in a try/catch statement. Any mistakes I'm doing in here?

Comment: `resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM AUTH;");` Um....wouldn't it make more sense to use a `WHERE` on that, rather than getting **all** of them and checking in a loop?!

Comment: That code looks like it should function (assuming it ends with closing the statement and returning false if the loop terminates without finding a match). `equalsIgnoreCase` is just fine for case-insensitive string matching. And assuming you don't care what the GUID is as long as it's not null...

Comment: Your `AUTH` table create statement says `GUID CHAR(36) NOT NULL`. But you're checking if getting `GUID` gives you non-`null`. Huh? Surely by definition, if there's a row in `AUTH`, `GUID` is non-null.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM AUTH WHERE username = <username>` does this query return a not null GUID for the above user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct your SQL query `select * from auth where username =  username;` and

```
 if (rs.next()){
//ResultSet is not empty
 }else {
//ResultSet is  empty
 }
```

Comment: Lol never thought of this. Could you explain why my code didn't work earlier?